# Loop through a folder containing images, resize images and place in new folder

Tags: c#

I have the following code that simple grabs a specific image and provide a fixed size regardless of the original size. This is the desire action.

The problem is, I must select each image from the source folder 1 at a time.

I need to loop though the Source folder, resize each image and then save the image in a destination folder. I am familiar with looping for files but not necessarily images.

*Code:*

```
class Program
{
    public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        var newImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingQuality =
           System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight);
        }

        return newImage;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Source\original_image.jpg");
        var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 150, 150);
        newImage.Save(@"C:\Dest\resized_image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try searching for how to get a list of all files in a directory?

Comment: "I am familiar with looping for files but not necessarily images". What does that mean? An "image" here is just a file. You search for them the same way you search for any file. The file extension strongly suggests its contents, but of course opening the file with `Image.FromFile()` is the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Source\")
            .GetFiles()
            .Where(f => f.IsImage());

foreach (var file in files)
{
      using (var image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName))
      {
            using (var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 150, 150))
            {
                try
                {
                    var newImageName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Dest\", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) + "_resized" + file.Extension);
                    newImage.Save(newImageName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsImage(this FileInfo file)
    {
        var allowedExtensions = new[] {".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg"};
        return allowedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that this can and will fail if there's other files (for example text files) in the same directory as it's currently written.  It's probably a good idea to wrap the using clauses in a try/catch block or so.

Comment: @user2366842, there you go... I've added some try catch and file type checks to avoid errors.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy, check my answer, I've added some updates.